# parse on buddy cli tool not working

Tags: parse-platform, command-line-interface, buddy.com

i have installed parse-on-buddy tool on my local and tried "talk" with parse.buddy.com .but http error 500 is shown.
my commaand is simple
parse-on-buddy -l which lists the available versions
please refer image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error happens if the environment variables that point to your app aren't set appropriately. If you have your app's ID and master key from the dashboard (https://parse.buddy.com) at App Settings -> Security & Keys, you should do the following:

For Windows PowerShell, use the following PowerShell commands, entering them one line at a time. Replace {Parse on Buddy App ID} and {Parse on Buddy Master Key} (including the braces { }) with the values from the dashboard:

$env:BUDDY_PARSE_APP_ID="{Parse on Buddy App ID}"

$env:BUDDY_PARSE_MASTER_KEY="{Parse on Buddy Master Key}"

For Windows cmd.exe, use the following commands, entering them one line at a time. Note that no quotes are used:

set BUDDY_PARSE_APP_ID={Parse on Buddy App ID}

set BUDDY_PARSE_MASTER_KEY={Parse on Buddy Master Key}

For MacOS/Linux, use the following commands, entering them one line at a time. Note that no quotes are used:

export BUDDY_PARSE_APP_ID={Parse on Buddy App ID}

export BUDDY_PARSE_MASTER_KEY={Parse on Buddy Master Key}

(reference: https://buddy.com/parse/cloud-code-web-hosting/)

If you're still having issues, please contact us at support@buddy.com.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: For those on mac, do not include {} 
source: it didn't work for me when included, but worked when removed